# unable to load PHP_ffmpeg.dll

Tags: ffmpeg, xampp, file-conversion

Been trying to make this work but no luck.

I always get

**PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ffmpeg.dll' - The specified module could not be found.**

1. Using XAMPP 1.7.4 on a Windows 7 64 Bit Computer.
2. Tried several php_ffmpeg.dll files restart but I still encounter the error.
3. Made sure that the dll is in C:\xampp\php\ext and copied the other DLL's on both system32 and SysWOW 64.
4. Was previously using the newest version of WAMPP but no luck so decided to go to XAMPP with a lower version.

If this doesn't work is there any other scripts I can use for converting uploaded audio files besides using FFMPEG? uploaded Audio files has a .wav extension..

Thanks

Comment: The same issue. My os is windows 7 and 32 bit.